# Traces into DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, trace, system.diagnostics

I have a referenced dll  to my project with traces using the TraceSource and it´s not working. My code in the dll project is something like this:

```
private static readonly TraceSource ts = new TraceSource("DataSource");
...
ts.TraceInformation(string.Format("Info: {0}", mess));
```

In the application project (where I import the DLL) the App.config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="MyListener" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>

    <sources>
      <source name="DataSource" switchValue="All">
        <listeners>
          <remove name="Default"/>
          <add name="MyListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>

    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="MyListener"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="c:\\temp\DefaultWriterOutput.log" />

    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

When I use a referenced project with the traces, all is working fine, but when I import the dll the trace is not working. Is there something wrong in the configuration?

Comment: "import the dll" do you mean include as a reference in another project? either way, the TRACE  flag must be set in the calling code. Is that the case? Do you define "not working" as a) no trace output happening or b) an exception?

Comment: Yes, the DLL reference in my application project. In the project properties->Build the Define TRACE Constant is checked but nothing changes

Comment: No trace output is happening. But if I reference to the project, the trace output is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that my DLL project is using a Nuget configuration (not Release). :( I set the  TRACE constant in the project properties into Nuget configuration and it works.